# Create a small 'window-form' application that runs anywhere

Tags: windows, linux, macos, programming-languages, widget

I work in the embedded world, using mainly C and no GUI at all (because there is no display screen).

Moving over to the non-embedded world, in which I have nearly no experience, what is the best programming environment (langauge/IDE/etc) for me to build a simple window-form application that will run on all the common platforms: windows/linux/mac-os ?

I do not want to build a web-app.

I have my eye on Python and one of it's widget libraries, QT or WxWidgets. Is that a good option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have both worked with PyQt and wxPython extensively.
PyQt is better designed and comes with very good UI designer so that you can quickly assemble your UI

wxPython has a very good demo and it can do pretty much anything which PyQT can do, I would anyday prefer PyQt but it may bot be free for commercial purpose but wxPython is free and is decent cross platform library.

Answer (score 3):

I like [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) personally but that or any of the ones you mentioned should be OK. I don't know which is the best in terms of least RAM usage.

Answer (score 2):

Both wx and QT have embedded/universal versions where the widgets are drawn directly.
They can both be called from python,but if you have a very small system python or py2exe might not be available.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to embed HtmlWindow I'd go with wxWindows... works everywhere without problems so far for me.

Comment: WxWindows has a goog thml control wxHtmlWindow

Answer (score 1):

[Qt](http://trolltech.com/downloads) is a good choice to start with. In my opinion it has a best (easy to use, simple & informative) API Documentation.  Package also includes many examples - from very basic to complex. And, yep, it`s truly crossplatform.

Check [Qt Licensing](http://trolltech.com/products/qt/learnmore/licensing-pricing/licensing) page, the library is free only for GPL projects.

I`m using [QDevelop](http://qdevelop.free.fr/) as text editor, but there are many other alternatives - [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/), [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/), [Code:Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), VS plugin & etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use swing and java? It is quite cross platform, and looks reasonable for form apps. If you squint a bit and ignore the java, its quite pleasant - or alternatively, use one of them dynamic languages on the JVM ([Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GUI+Programming+with+Groovy) is my recommended one).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of application is it going to be? Have you considered a web-based application instead? Web-based apps can be super flexible in that sense - you can run them on any platform that has a modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest choice for creating native cross-platform applications is [REALbasic](http://www.realsoftware.com).  Give it a try and you'll have a working app for Mac OS X, Windows and Linux in minutes.  No run-times or other stuff to worry about.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should try Html Application.It is something like web page it contain DHTML,java script,ActiveX but it is execute like .exe .

**Edit:**
Sorry for advice you html application.I just know it can run on windows only.